# Can't get basic Hello World Spring MVC project to work

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I downloaded and unzipped STS. I then started following the tutorial here that creates a simple Spring MVC application - http://www.javapassion.com/rebels/spring3_sts/

I go to File->New Spring Template Project->Spring MVC Project->(enter project name & package)->Finish

Then I  right-click my project->Run as->Run on Server->Finish

I get the following -
[image]

I then opened the pom.xml file, which seems to contain the error, and here is what the error it contains - [image]

So does anybody know what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have Maven installed?  

If that's not an issue, then you might want to make sure your dev machine can physically access the maven repository and there aren't any firewall issues there.

Comment: Now that error has disappeared but I am getting other errors in the console when I run the application. For example - Resource read error: Could not load org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable.class. Can't believe there is this much hassle running a simple helloworld application, I havent even wrote any code yet.

Comment: Have you ran maven:install yet?

Comment: I presume STS installs maven manually? Their docs say nothing about installing maven and maven's pom.xml file was created for my project automatically upon installation.

Comment: I deleted sts and reinstalled it and ran a new hello world application. Now the first error I get is - org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed. This is a joke. It seems to just throw out random errors. Never seen a framework so dodgy.

Comment: Deleted all the files in C:\Users\Me\.m2\Repository and now the hello world application runs. I can only imagine the sheer level of joy I will experience over the next few week learning spring considering it has taken me 5 hours to run a hello world application.

Comment: Wouldn't really blame that on Spring, that's more of a Maven issue.  Java frameworks are kind of a pain to set up, but once you get used to the structure, they're quite nice for app development.  You have to remember that Spring also tends to not hand hold TOO much, they expect you to have at least a little JavaEE experience in setting up containers, etc.  This isn't like Rails or Django where everything is very streamlined.

Comment: Ive gone right back to basics learning Tomcat and Java web applications in general. I can see it's not so bad now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple Jim. Don't panic.

Just right click on your project and then in **Run As** click on **Maven Install** option and go for some refreshments. When you'll come back after some time. Check your console. If it has stopped that means all your libraries needed to run this sample project is downloaded successfully by maven.

After that again right click on the project and go to **Run As** and click on **Maven Clean** that should build your project and create a war file for you. And don't forget to check the console that should say **Build Successful**.

After this just check your project structure. That should not show any red asteric mark anywhere in project.

And there you go. Now you can run your project successfully.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: Cheers mate, I have a better idea of the Spring system now, its not as bad as I thought, just alot to learn as with any new framework.